# Loopback & Angular : How to set default value in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

So I hit an error today when I tried to set value in my form.

this is my form:

```
<div class="list">
     <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.isActive" value="false">
     </label>
</div>
```

The value didn't appear when I put `ng-model="user.isActive"` in `<input>`.

Please looking for my code.
Thanks

Comment: Add `$scope.user = {};` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

use **ng-init**

```html
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.isActive" ng-init="user.isActive='yourvalue'">
```

Comment: `ng-init` is defined to use in `ng-repeat`. You should initialize object in controller.